# Spring AOP: passing target to Aspect

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I want to catch exceptions thrown by classes implementing *Processor* interface. In aspect I need an access to processor, which throws the exception. I define following pointcut:

```
@Pointcut("target(some.package.Processor) && args(message)")
  public void processor(Message message) {
}
```

And aspect:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="processor(message)", throwing="ex")
public void onExceptionInProcessor(Processor target, Exception ex, Message message) {
  // code skipped
}
```

However, I get following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301) ~[aspectjweaver-1.6.12.jar:1.6.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:209) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:263) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:295) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) ~[spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

What is a correct way of binding *target* object to aspect? The only way I've found is binding *JoinPoint*, but it suggests following:

> Unless you specifically need this reflective access, you should use
>   the target pointcut designator to get at this object for better static
>   typing and performance

Does anyone one how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `target` should refer to one of the parameter names in the method. For example saying

```
@Pointcut("target(myProc) && args(message)")
public void processor(Processor myProc, Message message) {
}
```

will give you the `Processor` in type safe way in `myProc` variable.

Comment: Seems like target(x) also needs to be specified first in the annotation, though not necessarily in the arguments