# Spring AOP: Passing parameter in aspect method

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-3

I am new to Spring AOP and trying to create a demo using `aop:around`.

A simple bean class:

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
public String getName() {
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Aspect implementation:

```
public class PrintingAspect {

public void performPrinting(ProceedingJoinPoint point){
    try {
        System.out.println("Before Printing!!!");
        point.proceed();        
        System.out.println("After Printing!!!");
    } catch (Throwable e) {         
        System.out.println("Exception Printing");
    }
}
}
```

Context XML:

```
<bean id="aspect" class="com.aop.aspect.PrintingAspect">        
</bean>    
<bean id="employee" class="com.aop.model.Employee">
    <property name="name" value="XXX"></property>
</bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="empName" expression="execution(* com.aop.model.Employee.getName(..))"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect">            
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="empName" method="performPrinting"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

App.java

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
    Employee empl = (Employee)context.getBean("employee");
    System.out.println("Employee Names: " + empl.getName());
}
}
```

The o/p I am getting is:

Before Printing!!!
Name: XXX
After Printing!!!
Employee Names: null

Why is the last one null ?

Comment: Which `Employee` object should be used as an argument?

Comment: the bean class posted at the top

Comment: That is a class. What _object_ do you want to be passed? The instance created by your `bean` declaration?

Comment: yes I want that to be passed

Comment: You've to autowire the Employee bean object in the aspect class.

Comment: I did that as you suggested: 1) Added a member variable `Employee empl;` in the aspect class and a setter so that Autowiring works 2) changed the xml to this: `<bean id="aspect" class="com.aop.aspect.PrintingAspect">
        <property name="empl" ref="employee"></property>
    </bean>` But now it is printing `Before Printing!!!` in an infinite loop - Any reasons for that?

Comment: You always end up in a loop because your aspect is on the `getName` method which you call inside the aspect, triggering again the aspect, which is calling again `getName`… etc. However to get access to the `Employee` you need modify your point cut. Try `execution(* com.aop.model.Employee.getName(..)) and this(empl)`, you might need to add `arg-names="empl"` to the `<aop:around ../>`, depending if the method argument names are still available or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with these changes:

XML:

```
<aop:pointcut id="empName"
        expression="execution(* com.example.Employee.getName(..))" />
```

Java:

```
public void performPrinting(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) { // Here empl is coming null
    System.out.println("Before Printing!!!");
    System.out.println(((Employee)jp.getTarget()).getName()); // empl is coming as NULL
    System.out.println("After Printing!!!");
}
```

In other words, you get access to the `target` which is the object that is being proxied for the AOP advice to be applied.

Comment: @user Pleased edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Done. I have added the code along with the o/p i am getting during execution.

Comment: @user182944 That happens because you've made your pointcut have a return type of `null`. Therefore the return value of `proceed` which is the return value of `getName()` is ignored. The apsect has to return something, but all it has is `null`.

Comment: @user182944 I'll maybe post it later, but there are more type safe ways to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904404/spring-aop-passing-target-to-aspect

Comment: A little improvement: You can bind the `target()` to a parameter and get rid of calling the getter all the time.

Comment: @kriegaex That's what I meant with the type safety. I don't have time to add it now. If you want, suggest an edit.

Comment: @kriegaex Can you please help me with a sinple demo on how to use `target()` ? What I did was added a return type `String` while invoking the `jp.invoke()` and returned that `String` to resolve that `null` issue. But since I am new to AOP, I want to follow the best practise that you suggested. Please help.

Comment: Actually user @SotiriosDelimanolis pointed to an example in his annotation (the one I just upvoted). Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Point.proceed() in the below code is responsible for actual exceution of the code and as your are using around advice you should capture the return value and return in the below method.
As you are return nothing in the below method Its coming as null.

Please let me know if it doesn't work.I haven't tested It But It will Work.

```
public void performPrinting(ProceedingJoinPoint point){
    try {
        System.out.println("Before Printing!!!");
        Object returnValue = point.proceed();        
        System.out.println("After Printing!!!");
    } catch (Throwable e) {         
        System.out.println("Exception Printing");
    }
return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example but I already tried this put before you posted. Looking at your code, it won't work for sure. Reason: 1) Your method is having a void return type and still you are returning an object. 2) Declare the object outside try block, else that variable wont be visible while returning. But I am ignore this mistake since it's out of this context.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake my intent was to tell the method should have some return type.

Answer (score 0):

@user182944, although you may have solved this long ago, I'm answering it because it may help others hitting the same issue!

Because your Aspect returns void (i.e. nothing), then any method you apply it to will return null.

With your current code, when you execute getName(), the Aspect kicks in and executes getName() but then throws away the result since your Aspect returns void, leaving your calling code with a null to deal with.
To ensure that the method you annotate returns the value you expect it to, you need your Aspect to return the object that's returned by it - i.e. by the `.proceed()` call.

In this case we know your method returns a String, so we could define the Aspect as returning a String. However, since we don't necessarily always know in advance what kind of object will be returned by the annotated method, the simplest solution is to declare your annotation with the return type `Object`.

So, to fix this, simply make your Aspect return the object returned by the annotated method, similar to @Rahul Jain's incomplete snippet), like this:

```java
public class PrintingAspect {

  public Object performPrinting(ProceedingJoinPoint point){
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Before Printing!!!");
        returnValue = point.proceed();        
        System.out.println("After Printing!!!");
    } catch (Throwable e) {         
        System.out.println("Exception Printing");
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

Now that we have an Aspect that returns the annotated method's response, we can execute our getName() method and our Aspect will kick in and then return the String that getName() returned, as you expected.

Hope this helps explain what's going on!